# Nested variable substitution in bash

Tags: bash, environment-variables, substitution

I cam across the pathmunge() function in /etc/bashrc. This is nice and useful in that it keeps duplicate entries out of the PATH.

But this should be a pattern for other vars as well: CDPATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH should not have duplicate entries. So I tried to write a varmunge function in the same manner. Here it is:

```
# varmunge() allows a one and only one addition of entries into the
# a PATH like environment variable. Good use cases for this function
# are: PATH, CDPATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH
# example: varmunge PATH $HOME/bin [after | before]
#!/bin/sh
varmunge () {
    case ":$1:" in
        *:"$2":*)
            ;;
        *)
            if [ "$3" = "after" ] ; then
                export $1=\$$1:$2         # These both fail
#                ${1}=${$1}:$2
            else
                export $1=$2:\$$1         # blech.
#                ${1}=$2:${$1}
            fi
    esac
}
```

But alas, it does not work. Can anyone fix my pathetic bash-ness?

Thanks ...

Posting the correct bash script in case other might want it.

```
#!/bin/sh
varmunge () {
    case ":${!1}:" in
        *:"$2":*)
            ;;
        *)
            if [ "$3" = "after" ] ; then
                eval ${1}=${!1}:$2
            else
                eval ${1}=$2:${!1}
            fi
    esac
}

varprint() {
    echo "${1}=${!1}"
}

# test varprint
VARTEST="path1:path2"
varprint VARTEST

# test varmunge
varmunge VARTEST path1
varmunge VARTEST path1 after
varmunge VARTEST path2
varmunge VARTEST path2 after
varmunge VARTEST path3
varmunge VARTEST path3 after
varmunge VARTEST path3
varmunge VARTEST path4 after
varmunge VARTEST path4

varprint VARTEST
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't explained what isn't working exactly but that is easy enough to figure out (or empirically test).

Anyway you have the same issue twice here (once you tried to work around but failed to use the construct that makes it work).

Your problem is that `$1` expands to the *name* of the variable you are trying to deal with not its value.

So when you call `varmunge PATH /some/path` and the `":$1:"` line is expanded you get `:PATH:` there where you intended to get `:<value of $PATH>:`.

To do that you need to use (bashism) [indirect expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Evaluating_indirect.2Freference_variables).

So you want `":${!1}:"` there.

Similarly, in the case bodies you tried to use the [`eval` indirect assignment](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#eval) pattern but `export` doesn't work that way so it never re-expands the escaped variable name.

Luckily, you don't need that trick here if you are going to use `export` since export does the assignment itself (similarly to `declare` and `printf -v`).

So you can use `export "$1=${!1}:$2"` and `export "$1=$2:${!1}"` as appropriate.

You could also use (bashism again) `printf -v "$1" -- %s "${!1}:$2"`, etc. if you didn't want to constantly re-export the variable.